# openshift v3 sed couldn't open temporary file

Tags: php, apache, docker, apache2, openshift

hi i tried to deploy my docker image to openshift online v3 but failed with message

> sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/php/7.0/apache2/sedJpqwn4:
>   permission denied

my docker image contain sed script like

```
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I'm new in openshift and docker how to solved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is writable, when using `sed -i` the directory must also be writable as `sed` will create a temporary file in that directory first.

My guess is the whole directory as well as the file isn't writable to the user the container is run as, which will effectively be a random user ID.

If you are constructing your own image, you need to make sure that any directories/files that your application, or startup code needs to modify, is group `root` and writable by group.

BTW, if this is your own image, why aren't you using the Source-to-Image builder for PHP instead?

Comment: when build to docker hub everything is ok, problem is when deploy to openshift online v3, um ok I'll learn this thanks

Comment: Go read https://blog.openshift.com/jupyter-on-openshift-part-6-running-as-an-assigned-user-id/ it talks a bit about how user IDs are assigned and the need to design images to deal with it. OpenShift doesn't by default allow you to run images as root or even a set user ID. It assigns you a user ID for your project and runs images under that user ID.

Comment: In general running images as root is a very bad idea and any platform which implements good security practices is not going to allow you to do it, as it makes it easier for someone to compromise the whole platform, and get access to other users applications, if any vulnerability is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching to root:

```
USER root
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
USER 185
```

The id "185" is the original user it starts with in the images I work with, you can test your case with:

```
RUN id -u
```

Just remember to switch back to the non-root, this is one of the openshift's restrictions related to docker.